# Display external link in modal panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have searched for this issue and although some of the solutions work none of them fit my issue.

I am creating links dynamically using ajax calls. When any of the links (styled as button) is clicked I need to show `http:\\<IP-address>` in the modal.

When links are created and I use "inspect" and copy what is rendered and paste it on top of the page and click it, it does show the content in modal pop up, so I know the script that displays content in modal works. But when I click on actual, dynamically created, links it opens the pop up with no content.

Here is a watered down version of what I have and what I have tried:

Modal popup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="printerInfoModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mainModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog fade in">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src="" id="modeliframe" style="zoom:0.60" frameborder="0" height="250" width="99.6%"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btnCloseModal" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>        

// Get a list of printers and for each get its status, printer property includes IP address
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Services/ps.asmx/GetPrinterMapping",
    cache: false,
    data: "",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response !== "") {
            try {
                jResponse = JSON.parse(response.d);
                    $.each(jResponse, function (index, value) {
                        var printer = value;

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: "Services/ps.asmx/GetPrinterStatus",
                            cache: false,
                            data: JSON.stringify({ PrinterHostnameIPAddress: printer.IPAddress }),
                            success: function (result) {
                                if (result !== "") {
                                    var printerIP = 'http://' + printer.IPAddress;
                                    //var redir = 'openInfo("' + printerIP + '")';

                                    if (status == "Ready") {
                                        $('<div/>', { class: 'col-sm-2' })
                                            .append($('<a/>', { id: 'printer' + printer.IDN, class: 'form-control btn btn-success btn-block extLink', style: 'margin-bottom:5px', href:printerIP, text: status.replace(/\"/g, '') }))
                                            .appendTo($('#printerStatusTable'));
                                        // Not sure if below two lines work!
                                        //It seems I cnnot add data-target: 'xxx' in attributes list part of "append"
                                        $('#printer' + printer.IDN).attr('data-target', '#printerInfoModal');
                                        $('#printer' + printer.IDN).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');

                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                            },
                            failure: function (result) {
                            }
                        });
                    })
$('#printerStatusTable').find('a').attr('data-target', '#printerInfoModal');
$('#printerStatusTable').find('a').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');

// Another think I tried
$('#printerStatusTable').find('a').attr('onclick', 'blah(' + $(this).attr('href') + ');');
```

JS:

```
// this function is hit if I copy/paste the html of the the link/button and click it; otherwise it is not called
$('.extLink').click(function (e) {debugger
    e.preventDefault();
    var frametarget = $(this).attr('href');
    //clearIframe();
    targetmodal = '#printerInfoModal'; 
    $('#modeliframe').attr("src", frametarget );   
});

function blah(){debugger
    var frametarget = $(this).attr('href');
    targetmodal = '#printerInfoModal'; 
    clearIframe();
    $('#modeliframe').attr("src", frametarget );   
}

function blah(frametarget){debugger
    //var frametarget = $(this).attr('href');
    targetmodal = '#printerInfoModal'; 
    clearIframe();
    $('#modeliframe').attr("src", frametarget );   
}

function clearIframe() {
    var iframe = $('#modeliframe');
    var html = "";

    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
}
```

This works, when I add the link manually; what I actually see when I click on the ajax-created link/button and select "inspect":

```
<a class="form-control btn btn-block extLink btn-success" id="printer10" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" href="http://1.2.3.4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#printerInfoModal">Ready</a>
```

Can anyone see what  am doing wrong or what I am missing?

Comment: Does the `.extLink` button always exist, in other words you're not dynamically creating it as part of an AJAX request?

Comment: If  understand your question correctly: buttons are being added dynamically and `.extLink` class applied to them. However, it is possible ajax call returns no printers and hence no button displayed. But for my testing, I see 4 printers listed.

Comment: Yeah. That's what i was after. Just wanted to know if the `.extLink` button was there when the page loads initially, which sounds like "no".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you are adding the button dynamically after the page loads, you'll need to target the document with your click handler like this:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.extLink', function() {
    // Do what you want when the button is clicked.
  });
```

This is because when your page loads all of your Jquery handlers are attached to the DOM. If the element doesn't exist, then you are attaching them to nothing basically.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that this solves all the issues. But since you mentioned that it doesn't get called when using dynamically created buttons, it was stands to reason this might help.

Comment: Still the same. Opens the modal with no content. JS function is not hit when I add `debugger`.

Comment: OK, this worked, sort of. I refresh the page every 10 seconds to check the status of the printers continuously. First time page loads, when I click the button, content is displayed in same browser window. However, after 10 seconds when page is reloaded, the content of `http://<ip-address>` is displayed in modal. I think it is due to the fact that when I create the links I cannot add data-target and data-toggle attributes (syntax error due to dash in attribute name) so I added these attributes outside of ajax call (see 4th line from bottom in example). If I can get this sorted I am good to go.

Comment: I think if you just wrap the data attributes in quotes it will work, so 'data-toggle': 'toggle' where you creating the `<a>` should work.

`$('<div/>', { class: 'col-md-2'}).append($('<a/>', { id: 'myId', class: 'my-class', href: 'http://google.com', 'data-toggle': 'toggle', text: 'Yes'} )).appendTo($('#content'));`